# Remove empty array from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `outer_array`. I try to push some array inside the `outer_array`. But some of the pushed array are empty. I don't want those empty array. I can remove it manually, but i need to delete it from the loop. here is my code:

```
var ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var splitLength = 3;
var outer_lis = [];
var first_limit = 0;
var second_limit = splitLength;
for (var i=0; i<ary.length; i++) {
  outer_lis.push(ary.slice(first_limit, second_limit));
  first_limit += splitLength;
  second_limit += splitLength;
}
console.log(outer_lis);

// Result
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [], [], [], [] ]
```

I searched for a solution but i got results in `php`. I dont understand `php`. If you can give me a solution for this problem its much appreciated. because i am a beginner in Javascript.

Comment: `; i < ary.length / splitLength; `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310865/remove-sub-array-item-in-javascript (duplicate)?

Comment: or simply later do `console.log(outer_lis  .filter(String)  );`, which skips empty arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to dandavis I got the solution. I change the code like this:

```
...
for (var i=0; i < ary.length / splitLength; i++) {
  outer_lis.push(ary.slice(first_limit, second_limit));
  first_limit += splitLength;
  second_limit += splitLength;
}
...
```

Now i got the result as i expected.

```
// Result
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[],[3,4,5]];
var newArr = arr.filter(function(item){
  return item.length !== 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will help you to achieve your result without empty array. in this code you can change your splitLength value also.

```js
var ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var splitLength = 3;
var outer_lis = [];
var first_limit = 0;
var second_limit = splitLength;
var looplimit = Math.ceil(ary.length / splitLength);
alert(looplimit);
for (var i = 0; i < looplimit; i++) {
  outer_lis.push(ary.slice(first_limit, second_limit));
  first_limit += splitLength;
  second_limit += splitLength;
}
console.log(outer_lis);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Here is the code

```js
var ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4],
        splitLength = 3,
        outer_lis = [],
        first_limit = 0,
        second_limit = splitLength,
        length = ary.length,
        totalSubArrays = Math.ceil(length/splitLength);

for (var i = 0; i < totalSubArrays; i++) {
  outer_lis.push(ary.slice(first_limit, second_limit));
  first_limit += splitLength;
  second_limit += splitLength;
}
console.log(outer_lis);
```